# Cannot install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Asus ROG Laptop

Tags: 16.04, asus

I have a Asus ROG G551VW laptop and I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop, but when i try to load the installer, my laptop just freezes and its fan starts working for no reason. I have tried to install Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop and the installation went smoothly. What should I do if I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might want to check with any other flavour of Ubuntu such as LUbuntu or XUbuntu and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NVIDIA graphics are glitchy with Ubuntu 15.10 and up. Some people don't have problems, while others get exactly what you're getting. Luckily, it's a pretty easy fix.

When the GRUB menu comes up, asking you what you want to do, highlight `Try Ubuntu` and press <kbd>E</kbd>. At the end of the line beginning with `linux`, enter `nouveau.modeset=0`. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot into the Live Session.

Once you install Ubuntu, you'll want to take a look here: [Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics)

Answer (score 2):

I am using ASUS ROG GL552VW and here's what I do to use Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop 64bit successfully:

1. During install, use `nouveau.modeset=0` kernel flag (see @TheWanderer's answer)
2. After installing, you need to use `nouveau.modeset=0` kernel flag again for first time.

   Then launch Software & Updates > Additional drivers, and install NVIDIA Proprietary Drivers.

Reboot and I'm good. :)

Note: I don't have to uninstall nouveau.