# Install Ubuntu on ASUS ROG

Tags: boot, windows, asus

I want to install Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on ASUS ROG GL552VX-CN059D in dual boot with Windows 10, but the system freeze after I try with option "Install Ubuntu" or "Try Ubuntu ..." from Grub.

What is the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: This question is already answered by Zacharee1. http://askubuntu.com/questions/820423/cannot-install-ubuntu-16-04-lts-on-asus-rog-laptop

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on my Asus machine. Try this, Highlight the try Ubuntu in the grub menu and then press the button  <kbd>e</kbd>  then in the line with Linux add the below command

```
nouveau.modeset=0
```

and then press <kbd>F10</kbd> after it. It disables the graphic driver and will now boot and won't freeze. Just make sure while installing to get the appropriate drivers during installation itself. I didn't do it so it got stuck for me on the purple screen after reboot.

If it also happens with you after rebooting. Then you should boot in the recovery mode and then install the graphics and missing drivers from the additional drivers in the dash. After that you will be able to boot up your Ubuntu.