# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 17.04 frame rate issues

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, 17.04, asus

I have a ASUS ROG G551VW and was able to install Ubuntu via [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/820423/cannot-install-ubuntu-16-04-lts-on-asus-rog-laptop).

Note that my laptop has a 4K display.

Every thing was smooth during live boot and testing but when I actually installed Ubuntu, each frame has to be drawn from the top, row by row until the whole frame was drawn.

It takes about 1 or 2 seconds to actually finish drawing a frame and start another one.

I have tried purging NVIDIA drivers and reinstalling them using TTY, but it didn't seem to help me. I also tried both Ubuntu versions and got the exact same problem with each of them. I also tried installing from scratch.

Please note that this laptop's GPU is GEFORCE 960M.

Is there any way of fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try installing `sudo apt install nvidia-prime` (you may have to first `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`) and then go to `nvidia-settings` and turn on your graphics card. (You're likely using Intel via an Optimus configuration)