# Ubuntu install not completing after liveboot media is ejected and system is restarted

Tags: software-installation

Hope someone can help me, I have an:
Mobo: Asus ROG-Strix 12cx
CPU: i79700k
RAM: 32 GB
GFX: GFeforce RTX 2060 TI

Used ventoy to setup the liveboot media as rufus resulted in the liveboot media not booting for the install. Creating the same behaviour as described below.

I can run the install from the Liveboot USB stick, but, when the time comes to remove the media and reboot then the install does not continue.

I get to the grub screen and select *Ubuntu hit enter and then my pc reboots and nothing else happens, I have left it for more than an hour and all there is, is a blank screen, my keyboards leds as well as the mouse leds switch off like the Bios does not boot further. I have to hard reset the power (hold down the power button).

I am at my wits end so any help is welcome, windows runs no problem, but don't want windows...

Edit for questions:

Ubuntu version 22.04.3
Single OS no dual boot.

Desktop version, Live boot works, after removing live boot media and restarting I am able to get to grub, after selecting *Ubuntu my keyboard and mouse are dead and screen is blank.Can boot to recovery, Yes.

No further updates for UEFI or SSD, video card is Geforce 2060 TI

**Edit 02**
@sudodus, I have gone through the links you suggested, however, I feel I now understand even less than before, I am totally new to Ubuntu, the devices I have had to load with Linux or Ubuntu, have usually just booted right up after live boot media was ejected, and this is the first time I am now facing these kinds of issues.....

I am not able to get Ubuntu to boot on it's own, my pc just goes and hangs, blank screen, dead keyboard and mouse, and I then need to force a power down by holing the power button till the PC switches off.

I held down the shift key, got into grub> advanced options for Ubuntu> Ubuntu, with Linux 6.2.0-37 generic does the following:

Loading Linux 6.2.0-37 generic...
Loading initial ramdisk...
_

And stops there, the cursor does not flash anymore, my keyboard and mouse lights go off and everything just stops.

Forcing the power off, and then rebooting the PC and held down the shift key, got into grub> advanced options for Ubuntu> Ubuntu, with Linux 6.2.0-37 generic (recovery mode)

boots all the way through to the recovery screen, if I then select "resume" it boots into Ubuntu without any problems....

Until the next reboot and then I have to repeat everything from above...

Thanks
Regards
Charles

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install? Are you trying to install the server or the desktop version? Are you trying to make a dual boot setup with Windows and Ubuntu, or is this computer going to have Ubuntu only? [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1495669/edit) and add the answers to all these questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Asus ROG Laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/820423/cannot-install-ubuntu-16-04-lts-on-asus-rog-laptop)

Comment: Have you updated UEFI firmware and if SSD, SSD firmware? What video card/chip? Can you boot recovery mode in grub menu, if install boots to grub menu?

Comment: Ubuntu version 22.04.3
 single os no dual boot.

Desktop version, Live boot works, after removing live boot media and restarting I am able to get to grub, after selecting *Ubuntu my keyboard and mouse are dead and screen is blank.

No further updates for UEFI or SSD, video card is Geforce 2060 TI

Comment: I suspect that the built-in graphics driver does not work with your nvidia card. Please boot in recovery mode or add the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset` on the 'linux' line in grub configuration file `grub.cfg`. If that helps, the next step would be to try with a proprietary nvidia driver to release the full power of the graphics card.

Comment: @sudodus I am a total noob, How do I do what you have asked? Any links to read up on would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What about the 'red and underlined' link in my previous comment? And links from that link. Look for the instructions for 'grub boot'. If still problems, please explain what details are difficult (to do or to understand).

Comment: Sorry did not know what that meant, thank you I will go look at that and revert back with any further development.

Comment: @sudodus I have posted another edit above if you do not mind taking a look there  please.. Thank you.

Comment: So recovery mode in the installed system works. I suggest the following: When booted and running like that (recovery mode - installed system), in a terminal window `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` try by adding `nomodeset` or `nouveau.modeset=0` so one of the lines will be **`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"`** or `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0"`. Save the file and run `sudo update-grub`. Now after reboot, it will work (I hope). If this is the case, the next improvement will be to try to install a proprietary driver for your nvidia graphics ...

Comment: Hi @sudodus, tried both line types, does not help same behavior, even tried GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash noveau.modeset=1920x1080x32 also did not help.

Comment: You may find new helpers if you start a thread at the [Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org), and someone there might find a solution for you. - By the way, did you remember to run `sudo update-grub` ?

Comment: Hi @sudodus ok, will try that, yes did do update grub.... Thank you for your time and patience.

Answer (score 0):

may be problem with build-in graphics card as its normal in Ubuntu to create   glitch  video drive try
When the GRUB menu comes up, asking you what you want to do, highlight Try Ubuntu and press E. At the end of the line beginning with Linux enter {nouveau.modeset=0}. Press F10 to boot into the Live.
or
try disable graphics in bios before installing.

Comment: The live boot USB works fine it boots without any issue, the problem comes when live boot must be ejected so that the pc can restart and complete the install, it does not boot after that. Mobo does not have on board gfx only external rtx 2060 ti. Any other suggestions please?